# Eval function in react-native android does not understand ES6

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to use eval() in my react-native android app. The eval executes a bunch of code(installs few BOTS) from a js file after the app is launched.It goes like this.

// Load the JS file using an asset fetcher
// eval(response from asset fetcher)

The above logic works perfectly fine in IOS. But when the code is executed in android i keep getting compilation errors. The JS file which i am trying to load has ES6 syntax like let,const,await,async etc. The strange thing is when i switch on the 'Debug JS Remotely' option in emulator, eval gets executed without giving errors. My guess is that code gets compiled with chrome browser.But this workaround will not work @production environment. Can anyone pls suggest an alternative to eval() or Function().

Comment: Always Babel everything down to ES5 in production code in order to support the not-insignificant market share of browsers that don't support ES6+.

Comment: But how to Babel before passing the code to eval(). React does it automatically. But how to do manually